# MacBook Pro 2009, can't format/fresh install

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, startup, disk-format

So, i'm in a (bit of) a pinch.

I was doing a format/fresh install of MacOS on my old 13-inch 2009 MacBook Pro going through OS X Utility and *Reinstall OS X*. Unfortunately when i do enter my Apple credentials for autentication i get a loathsome **"This item is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later"** error.

I've tried logging into iCloud as said in this thread https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6455578?tstart=0 but while i do log correctly i get the same error.

Please bear in mind that:

- Maybe it was stupid of me, but since i though i wouldn't have any problem doing this i've already formatted my HD, and i should have done it anyway since i planned to wipe that drive. So i can't download an image of the OS from Apple Store and create a bootable drive.
- I don't remember exactly which version of OSX i had on the machine since i wasn't using it regularly, but it was slightly outdated and could have been 10.9.
- I still have the original install DVD for 10.6 but for whatever reason i am not able to boot from DVD holding C at boot.

Hope someone here can help me and thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Amongst your options are - 1) get a friend to DL the latest OS X Installer & make a boot USB. 2) Take it to an Apple Store & they'll do it for you

Comment: Oh, bummer. I do not have any other option, really? Taking it to and Apple Store isn't an option, i do not have any in a ~200 miles radius. 

Thank you for the answer ;-)

Comment: I've discovered empirically that the DVD drives on old machines [any type] just get 'tired' over the years & stop reading/writing properly. Maybe another alternative is an external DVD, but I've never tried that myself. The machine's too old to use Internet Recovery, so it's got to be something physical.

Answer (score 1):

So, happy - more or less - ending. I contacted an authorised reseller and they made me a bootable USB. now i have a working machine but the situation still sucks, mostly the whole installer dvd thing. And the fact that you can't download an .iso from an official Apple source even if you legitimately purchased a Mac.